# Comparison of cohomologies on two sites

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory

Let $C$ be a category with two different topologies $\tau_1, \tau_2$ such that $\tau_1$ is stronger, i.e. any covering in $\tau_2$ is also a covering in $\tau_1$. Denote the corresponding sites by $C_1, C_2.$
Let $F \in Sh(C_1)$, in particular, $F$ is also a sheaf with respect to $\tau_2$. Definitely, we should not have $H^i (C_1, F) = H^i (C_2, F)$ but I am confused because:

1. Choose an injective resolution $F \to I_0 \to I_1 \to .. $ where $I_j \in Sh(C_1)$ are injective sheaves.
2. Each $I_j$ is also in $Sh(C_2)$ and is injective.
3. Suppose $C$ has a final object $X$, then we just compute cohomology of $I_0 (X) \to I_1 (X) \to ..$ and by construction they compute both $H^i (C_1, F)$ and $H^i (C_2, F)$.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Part 2 looks the most suspicious to me - injectivity can be slippery to pin down and may change in surprising ways under simple functors. Can you elaborate on your argument there?

Comment: @KReiser Yes, I suspect that part 2 is wrong. If G is an injective tau_1 sheaf, then to check that it is an injective tau_2 sheaf we need to check that for any two tau_2 sheaves A,B with a map 0 -> A -> B and A -> G one can extend it to B -> G. Definitely, we should use that G is an injective tau_1 sheaf but A, B are not necessarily tau_1 sheaves since tau_1 has more coverings.
E.g. for X_{zar} and X_{et}  we have a lot of Zariski sheaves. In particular, an injective etale sheaf G is not necessarily an injective Zariski sheaf since we have a lot Zariski sheaves A, B with A->G and 0->A->B.

Comment: There are fewer $\tau_1$-sheaves (because $\tau_1$ is stronger), so it is indeed easier for a $\tau_1$-sheaf to be injective. Moral: injectivity is not an intrinsic property of objects but depends on the ambient category.